# How does random number probabilities work in distributed systems?

Tags: distributed-systems, randomness, pseudo-random-generators

Let's say I have a code which does coin toss at 25% win probability.

1. If I run this code n number of times in the same system it will yield ~25% win.
2. If I run this code on n devices (once each) will the result be ~25%.

n = very large number.

Are my assertions right?

Edit:My key doubt was, since computers use pseudo random numbers (which are based on a seed), will this affect this assertion (especially #2)

Comment: Probability works in exactly the same way, regardless of what is being analyzed. This is the power of mathematics.

Comment: Since all computer random numbers are "pseudo" and based on seeds, could this have a different effect was my question.

Comment: If all the seeds are the same, the expectation will still be 25%, but the variance will be huge.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this is a consequence of the Law of Large Numbers.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Yes - it still holds for pseudorandom number generators if they are any good.

Seed each PRNG independently.

Comment: Probably I missed the key component of my question. Will "pseudo random generator" impact the result, since it is seed based.

Comment: @Codevalley, I edited my answer.